# Changing the auto-generated kops kubernetes admin password

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

I have been using kops to build the kubernetes cluster which is really easy-to-go tool, however i am unable to find a way-out on how to change the admin password which is auto-generated while the cluster is being created.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> As it is currently not possible to modify or delete + create secrets of type "Secret" with the CLI you have to modify them directly in the kops s3 bucket.
>
> They are stored /clustername/secrets/ and contain the secret as a base64 encoded string. To change the secret base64 encode it with:
>
> `echo -n 'MY_SECRET' | base64`
>
> and replace it in the "Data" field of the file. Verifiy your change with get secrets and perform a rolling update of the cluster

Seen in **Managing secrets** Kops’s documentation: [Workaround for changing secrets with type "Secret"](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/secrets.md#workaround-for-changing-secrets-with-type-secret)